# Selenium/Python: Why do all detected elements have coordinates at a y position of y: 1 or y: 0?

Tags: python, selenium

My element coordinates appear to be all stuck at y=0 and y=1, and so I cannot scroll to them. I am coding using Python and have obtained a list of elements in the website with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

bot = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'\geckodriver.exe')
bot.get('URL')
bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
time.sleep(1)
xpath = "//div[@data-testid='something']"  
el = bot.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
```

I am trying to scroll to each element with:

```
coords = []
print("Getting coords")
for x in range(len(el)):
    coords.append(el[x].location_once_scrolled_into_view)
for x in coords:
    print(x)
for x in range(len(coords)):
    print(x)
    bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo({}, {});'.format(coords[x]['x'], coords[x]['y']))
print("Done")
```

My sample output is:

```
length of elements is: 28
Getting coords
{'x': 622, 'y': 1}
{'x': 622, 'y': 0}
{'x': 622, 'y': 1}
...
```

Edit: The question has been downvoted. I didn't explain earlier attempts but I'm guessing the downvote may be due to lack of research. I'm editing this question to show all my attempts:

**Attempt 1:** Element may be invisible. Try to wait until element is clickable/visible

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

Result/Output (1) : Partial success. After running element_to_be_clickable, the last two elements have actual y coordinates (if I don't use it all y coordinates are either 0 or 1). I think the problem may be with element_to_be_clickable - is it possible to run this for each of the 28 elements discovered?:

```
{'x': 622, 'y': 77}
{'x': 621, 'y': 168}
```

**Attempt 2:** Try to make sure all detected elements are clickable - if this works enclose it in a while loop.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(el[1]))
```

Result/Output (2): TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not FirefoxWebElement

**Attempt 3:** Maybe not enough elements are present. Try to load all elements.

```
while True:               
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        elements = bot.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        counter = len(elements)
        print(counter)
        if counter > 10:
            break
```

Result/Output (3): No change. Increasing the counter minimum just returns more coordinates with y:1 or y:0

**Attempt 4:** Give enough time for elements to finish loading

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

Result/Output (4): No change

Edit2 **Attempt 5** Check for visibility of all elements

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

Result/Output (5): No change - only returns results of coordinates y = 0 and y = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that GeckoDriver 0.27 does not scroll to the elements in FireFox v79 and Selenium 3.141 (at least visibly) when running .location_once_scrolled_into_view. The solution is to use .location instead so that the DIV element is in view (Selenium Python docs [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)):

```
    for x in range(len(el)):
        coords.append(el[x].location)
```

Results:

```
17
length of elements is: 17
Getting coords
{'x': 617, 'y': 4786}
{'x': 622, 'y': 4958}
{'x': 617, 'y': 5049}
{'x': 622, 'y': 5356}
{'x': 622, 'y': 5923}
...
```